How to Convert ParentFolderID (stored ID) to Matching REST ID in Microsoft Graph API
ParentFolder ID of the calendar ID retrieve from Audit Log
I converted this ParentFolderID to an entry ID using some code logic:
Then, I converted the entry ID to a REST ID using the Microsoft Graph Explorer:Entry ID to Rest ID
Then make an graph API request using converted restID.Graph API request using that ID
Why is there a difference between the actual REST ID obtained from the Graph API response and the REST ID converted from the ParentFolderID? Is there any way to convert these IDs so that they match and work consistently in Graph API requests?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

as long as your using translateExchangeId from the Graph the results of this should always be consistent.  They don't document the id format used (so in the case they are using a different version) but the different versions should be backwards compatible.
